# Google Maps - Looping through array for polyline

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-markers, polyline

I want to loop through an array of coordinates that I want to use for markers and drawing a line in google maps.
Is there a solution to create the path property with a loop of const locations?

Please check my example below:

```
const lineSymbol = {
  path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
  strokeColor: "red",
      scale: 4
};

const locations = [
      ["Tampere", 61.50741562413278, 23.75886761967578,  1, "Termin: xx.xx"],
      ["Helsinki", 60.219957, 25.196776,  2, "test2"],
      ["Travemünde", 55.778989, 18.271974,  2, "test3"],
      ["Stuttgart", 48.7733567672875, 9.174572759931003, 3, "test4"],
      ["Ludwigsburg", 48.8893286910321,  9.197454231637288, 4, "test5"],
]

const line = new google.maps.Polyline({

    path: [
        { lat:  locations[0][1], lng: locations[0][2] },
        { lat:  60.219957, lng:  25.196776 },
        { lat:  locations[2][1], lng: locations[2][2] },
        { lat:  53.941362, lng:  10.860464 },
        { lat: 48.7733567672875, lng: 9.174572759931003 },
    ],
    strokeColor: "red",
        scale: 7,
    icons: [
        {
          icon: lineSymbol,
          offset: "100%",
        },
    ],
 map: map,
});
```

By using above code it creates in Google Maps this:

[The result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edimA.jpg)

Comment: What do you mean by "Is there a solution to create the path property with a loop of const locations".  Your picture looks like what I would expect from the posted code.  Do you expect a different result?

Comment: Your picture doesn't match the data in your question.

Comment: The data should match. But that's not the point. Let's say I would add 50 further location. What I would like to avoid to add all of them additionally to polyline path property. The path values should be created out of the const locations array. How can I pull the data out of locations and use them for path. Is there any function or loop which could be achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process your input array and create a polyline in a loop:

```
var path = [];
for (var i=0; i<locations.length; i++) {
  // add to polyline
  path.push({lat: locations[i][2], lng: locations[i][1]});
  // create marker
  new google.maps.Marker({
    position: path[path.length-1],
    map: map
  })
}
const line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: path,
    strokeColor: "red",
        scale: 7,
    icons: [
        {
          icon: lineSymbol,
          offset: "100%",
        },
    ],
 map: map,
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/omb60qwe/)

(note that the data in your question doesn't match your picture)

[image: screenshot of result]

**code snippet:**

```js
// This example creates a 2-pixel-wide red polyline showing the path of
// the first trans-Pacific flight between Oakland, CA, and Brisbane,
// Australia which was made by Charles Kingsford Smith.
function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: -180
    },
    mapTypeId: "terrain",
  });
  const lineSymbol = {
    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW,
    strokeColor: "red",
    scale: 4
  };

  const locations = [
    ["Tampere", 61.50741562413278, 23.75886761967578, 1, "Termin: xx.xx"],
    ["Helsinki", 60.219957, 25.196776, 2, "test2"],
    ["Travemünde", 55.778989, 18.271974, 2, "test3"],
    ["Stuttgart", 48.7733567672875, 9.174572759931003, 3, "test4"],
    ["Ludwigsburg", 48.8893286910321, 9.197454231637288, 4, "test5"],
  ]
  var path = [];
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    path.push({
      lat: locations[i][2],
      lng: locations[i][1]
    });
    bounds.extend(path[path.length - 1]);
    new google.maps.Marker({
      position: path[path.length - 1],
      map: map
    })

  }

  const line = new google.maps.Polyline({

    path: path,
    strokeColor: "red",
    scale: 7,
    icons: [{
      icon: lineSymbol,
      offset: "100%",
    }, ],
    map: map,
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Polylines</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&v=weekly&channel=2" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```